# C++ - Trouble with pointers, function and 2D Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

Can someone explain why my code isn't working?

```
class Angry{    
private:
    char** cenario;
public:
    Angry();
    void read(char**, std::fstream&);
};

//call
Angry::Angry() {
   fstream blocks(...);
   read(cenario, blocks);
   blocks.close();
}

//trying to make a 2D array in cenario
void Angry::read(char** block, std::fstream& file) {
    int x, y;
    file >> x;
    file >> y;
    block = new char*[y];
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        block[i] = new char[x];
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
            file >> block[i][j];
}
```

There's no error message but the program crashes when I try to access any value of "cenario".
I'm trying to use 'block' to make and fill the 2D array cenario.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: cenario (scenario?) is a pointer with an arbitrary (non-initialized) value. So it points somewhere in your memory. And then probably the read call starts writing there. If I were a computer I'd crash too. You should first allocate memory, e.g. with new.

Comment: Use `std::vector`. **Do not use `new[]`.**

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge, it's cenario (portuguese). I want to create a array dynamically, that's why I declare cenario that way. If you look at the 'read' function, you'll see that I'm making and filling the array but it's not working.

Comment: Your read function cannot change your cenario pointer, since it is passed by value, rather than by reference. So after the read call cenario is still a pointer to an arbitrary block of memory, not to the memory you allocated.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge you got what I want, but can you explain me how to do?

Comment: @LuizH.Dias `void Angry::read(char**& block, std::fstream& file) {` Use a reference.

Comment: Change the signature of read to: `void Angry::read(char** &block, std::fstream& file) {`